# Spring default profile properties

Tags: java, spring, profile, spring-profiles

I have next issue.

I'm using following configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/main.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:config/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
</bean>
```

And it works perfectly if I use `-Dspring.profiles.active` argument. But if I do not use this argument and rely on

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

then I get next exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0' defined in URL [file:/Users/mlinkov/Projects/target/WEB-INF/classes/main-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in string value "classpath:config/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in string value "classpath:config/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1809)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in string value "classpath:config/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitList(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208)
... 56 more
```

despite I see following in logs

```
INFO PropertiesLoaderSupport.java 2015-09-16 20:58:47,730:   Loading properties file from class path resource [config/main.properties]


INFO PropertiesLoaderSupport.java 2015-09-16 20:58:47,731:   Loading properties file from class path resource [config/application-dev.properties]
```

As I understand it happens because web.xml `context-param` is not system variable. Is there way to specify profile properties file by using default value rather than `-Dspring.profiles.active` variable?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I have found out why I get exception.

`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is used for setting placeholders from property file and system variables. If I explicitly define `system.profiles.active` variable through startup arguments, spring register this variable as system, otherwise, I mean getting variable from web.xml `context-property`, it does not become system variable so we get exception when `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` tries to get placeholder by `system.profiles.active`.

I hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

In non-DEV environments your rely on `spring.profiles.active` explicitly defined. So I would suggest avoiding default configuration to DEV, because it create difference against non-DEV environments and **you want to be as close to PROD as possible in your configs**.

Also change the name of placeholder string (e.g. to `environment.type`), because `spring.profiles.active` can change behavior of you application by enabling/disabling `@Profile` annotated beans. Again you want to minimize such differences between environments as much as possible.

Comment: However is there way to make it work without explicitly defined variable in args? Actually i did it by using ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which allows to take placeholder from web.xml. But unfortunately this class is deprecated

Comment: Am i correct by thinking that exception in topic caused because PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer initialize placeholders by locations and system variables, then he finds ${spring.profiles.active} in context which does not have appropriate placeholder?